# Array slow elements removal

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have array and I want to remove N elements from its head.

Lets say, array (with floats) has 1M elements and I want first 500K to go out. I have two ways, call shift 500K times in loop or call splice(0,500000).

The thing is, first solution is horrible idea (it's very very slow). Second is slow too because splice returns removed part from array in a new array (well, it just allocate 500K floats and throw them out of window).

In my app, I'm doing some things with really big matrices, and unfortunately, elements removal via splice is slow for me. Is there some faster way how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that `Array#slice` would be at *least* as fast as either of those options and probably faster. It does mean temporarily allocating duplicated memory, but 1M numbers is only about 64MB of memory (assuming the JavaScript engine has been able to use a true array under the covers), so temporarily having the original 64MB plus the 32MB for the ones you want to keep before releasing the original 64MB seems fairly cheap:

```
array = array.slice(500000);
```

This also has the advantage that it won't force the JavaScript engine into using an object rather than an array under the covers. (Other things you're doing may cause that, but...)

You've said you're doing this with floats, you might look at using `Float64Array` rather than untyped arrays. That limits the operations you can perform, but ensures that you don't end up with unoptimized arrays. When you delete entries from arrays, you can end up with unoptimized arrays with markedly slower access times than optimized arrays, as they end up being objects with named properties rather than offset accesses. (A good JavaScript engine will keep them optimized if it can; using typed arrays would help prevent you from blowing its optimizations.)

This (dashed off and quite certainly flawed) NodeJS test suggests that `splice` is anywhere from 60% to 95% slower than `slice`, and that V8 does a great job keeping the array optimized as the result for the typed array is virtually identical to the result for the untyped array in the `slice` case:

```
"use strict";
let sliceStats = createStats();
let sliceTypedStats = createStats();
let spliceStats = createStats();
for (let c = 0; c < 100; ++c) {
    if (test(buildUntyped, sliceStats, testSlice).length != 500000) throw new Error("1");
    if (test(buildTyped, sliceTypedStats, testSlice).length != 500000) throw new Error("2");
    if (test(buildUntyped, spliceStats, testSplice).length != 500000) throw new Error("3");
    console.log(c);
}
console.log("slice     ", avg(sliceStats.sum, sliceStats.count));
console.log("sliceTyped", avg(sliceTypedStats.sum, sliceTypedStats.count));
console.log("splice    ", avg(spliceStats.sum, spliceStats.count));

function avg(sum, count) {
    return (sum / count).toFixed(3);
}

function createStats() {
    return {
        count: 0,
        sum:   0
    };
}
function buildUntyped() {
    let a = [];
    for (let n = 0; n < 1000000; ++n) {
        a[n] = Math.random();
    }
    return a;
}

function buildTyped() {
    let a = new Float64Array(1000000);
    for (let n = 0; n < 1000000; ++n) {
        a[n] = Math.random();
    }
    return a;
}

function test(build, stats, f) {
    let a;
    let ignore = 0;
    let start = Date.now();
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        let s = Date.now();
        a = build();
        ignore += Date.now() - s;
        a = f(a);
    }
    stats.sum += Date.now() - start - ignore;
    ++stats.count;
    return a;
}

function testSlice(a) {
    return a.slice(500000);
}
function testSplice(a) {
    a.splice(0, 500000);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: It's not a cheap if you do it again and again in cycle.

Comment: I use matrices for neural network computation in evolution algorithm, I can't just allocate 32MB for fun.

Comment: @Seraph: The point is that you're releasing the previous memory, so it's churn rather than aggregate; depending on what else is going on, you may not even notice that churn. And it's not just "for fun;" you don't have a lot of good options here. A quick (and therefore imperfect) test on NodeJS suggests `splice` is 60% slower than `slice` at this operation (16ms vs. 10ms for 1000 iterations on my machine), so that's a substantial improvement.

Comment: Thank you for test. It's really faster, but not enough for my needs, I used it instead of splice solution, but problems remains unsolved.

Comment: @Seraph: Yeah, this may just not be something you can reasonably do in JavaScript. :-|

Comment: WOW thanks for idea of typed arrays, I totally forgot that they exists. I will try them.

Answer (score 1):

[Immutable.js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) solves this problem by structural sharing. It does not copy the entries as splice would do but returns a reference on the included 
parts of the array. You would need to move your array to the Immutable.js data structure and then call the immutable operation [splice](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/splice).

Comment: This has two problems. First is, efficient immutable structures uses recursive structures (linked nodes) which causes slow acces time (I need very fast acces time).

Second, I can't move it from because it will be again, copying of 1M elements.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Typed enter isntead of shift+enter

Comment: are you sure? I think in JavaScript this kind of linking is impossible and the data structure is implemented in another way. AFAIK

Comment: It's possible as long as language has references. Immutable structure can't be array or array like because every change can be done only through new copy and new copy of full array is absurdly slow. If you use some node based structure (recursive), this copy is very cheap because you can link you new copy to parts of original structure. You only need to copy nodes from root to to changed node, every other branch is linked back (list is only degenerated tree to one branch). Just try to implement some immutable search tree in JS.